# Get distance between two web elements in Python?

Tags: python, web, browser, distance, element

Say I have

```
<body>
    <div id="container1"><div>
    <div id="container2"><div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to get the distance between `container1` and `container2` after it has rendered in the browser? With distance I mean the actual distance as the user sees it between the two elements, either in pixels, inches or whatever.

Comment: Not without having a rendering engine actually render the DOM and apply CSS to it. Even then, what if the user has a large default font size configured in his browser? That might very well affect the distance between those two elements, and it might be slightly different for every user because of other factors.

Comment: By the way, I ended up doing my [own library](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-rectangles) since I needed more complicated calculations like finding the **minimum distance of two elements diagonally**. What I did was to convert each selenium object to a rectangle in my library and then simply get the distance between the two rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

This is very platform/browser dependent but you can try Selenium + PhantomJS. For example lets find the distance between two links in the [main Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page):
[image]

**Install dependencies:**

1. Install NodeJS:
2. Install phantomjs: `npm -g install phantomjs`
3. Install selenium: `pip install selenium`

**Python:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')

main_page_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#n-mainpage-description a')
help_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#n-help a')

help_link.location['y'] - main_page_link.location['y']
# 159 px
```

For Chrome/Firefox etc you just need to install the corresponding web driver and change:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # or
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

As an example of the rendering differences, with Chrome in Mac I get 171px while in Firefox I get 164px.

Comment: I have a minor question. What happens if you try to get the distance between an element and a container where the element is within? Will that yield `0`?

Comment: @Pithikos, If there is no padding, margin, ... set, then yes, it will be 0.